# Creating entity with Magical Record only in OSX (+entityForName: could not locate an entity named '(null)' in this model.)

Tags: macos, core-data, magicalrecord

Hi I am having a problem creating entitys with magicalRecord in OSX, I create the model and the NSManagagedSubclasses and so on. But when i run this code in applicationDidFinishLaunching(I am using magicalRecord 2.2):

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];
Person * person = [Person MR_createEntity];
person.name = @"alex";
```

I get this in the log:

```
2013-10-06 18:01:54.320 TestMagicalRecord[7554:303] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x7fff71a96238) -> Created Context UNNAMED
2013-10-06 18:01:54.321 TestMagicalRecord[7554:303] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x7fff71a96238) Set Root Saving Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x101924d00>
2013-10-06 18:01:54.321 TestMagicalRecord[7554:303] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_newMainQueueContext](0x7fff71a96238) Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1001564a0>
2013-10-06 18:01:54.321 TestMagicalRecord[7554:303] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x7fff71a96238) Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1001564a0>
2013-10-06 18:01:54.322 TestMagicalRecord[7554:303] +entityForName: could not locate an entity named '(null)' in this model.
```

When i run the same code in an IOS project it runs with no problems, i have been trying to find sample code for OSX but with no luck, should it be any different?

The Mac sample code in the Magical record Github repo does only contain a project is there a way to run it with the other resources?

I bet its a simple solution but i cant find anything in the Docs/SO that will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you also found out in the mean time, this is a bug in the Development branch of Magical Record.

In the 2.2 version of the Development branch, `MR_createEntity` uses the following method to determine the entity name of the object that should be created:

```
+ (NSString *) MR_bestGuessAtAnEntityName
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(entityName)])
    {
        return [self performSelector:@selector(entityName)];
    }
    return NSStringFromClass(self);
}
```

But (at least on OS X 10.8), `NSObject` actually *responds* to `entityName`, and invoking
that method returns `nil`. I could not find any documentation on this, so this might be
some internal undocumented method.

But the effect is that `MR_bestGuessAtAnEntityName` returns `nil`, and therefore

```
+ (id) MR_createInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[self MR_bestGuessAtAnEntityName] inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

fails with the error message

```
+entityForName: could not locate an entity named '(null)' in this model.
```

So this is a Magical Record bug, and is worth reporting to the maintainers.
The bug occurs only on OS X, because `NSObject` (or `NSManagedObject`) does not respond to `entityName` on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model file is being compiled as part of your target. You can see this by selecting the xcdatamodel file in the project navigator, and then in the inspector area, look for the targets it belongs to. Or, you can check your build settings and make sure this file is in the compile files section.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, the xcdatamodel file is added to the target. and the DefaultContext is not nil(if that helps).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i did not use the right Branch from Github I had the Development branch instead of the Master Branch! Hope that this helps others who make this stupid mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Like Martin R!

- Go to file `NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.m`
- Find method: `+ (NSString *) MR_bestGuessAtAnEntityName`
- Replace by: `return NSStringFromClass(self);`

Work fine.